# Parameter pack, capture clause and initializers

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates

<sub>**Note**: this question is for the sake of curiosity.</sub>

---

Consider the documentation for the [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and the one for the [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

The following code is legal:

```
template<typename... T>
void f(T... t) {
    auto lambda = [t...](){ /* do something */ };
    // do something else
}
```

The same goes without saying for this one:

```
void f(int i) {
    auto lambda = [i = i](){ /* do something */ };
    // do something else
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to define an initializer in the capture clause for a parameter pack.
Something like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) {
    auto lambda = [params = std::forward<Args>(args)...](){ /* do something */ };
    // do something else
}
```

Ok, I suspect it doesn't make sense, but it gives an idea at least.
Is there any viable solution to do that?

---

<sub>Please, do not ask me why I would do that. I don't want to do that. As I said, it's for the sake of curiosity.</sub>

Comment: capture parameter pack cannot use generalized capture as far as I know

Comment: given that `args` are passed by value, their types have already decayed, so `[args = args...]` would always be the same as `[args...]`, right?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Right, let me slightly change it using `std::forward`. I didn't imagine these details would have affected the answer so much, sorry.

Comment: init-captures can't be pack expansions. The workaround is usually capturing a tuple and then unpacking it inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

Best you can do is:

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) {
  auto lambda = [params = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()
  { /* do something */ };
  // do something else
}
```

then interact with `params` as a `tuple`, including using `get`.

I find you end up having to leave the world of lambdas to unpack the elements again.  Probably you could do it with a helper like this:

```
template<std::size_t...Is, class F>
decltype(auto) unpack_impl( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f ) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}...);
}
template<std::size_t N, class F>
decltype(auto) unpack( F&& f ) {
  return unpack_impl( std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

which takes a template non-type argument `N`, then generates a pack of `integral_constants` with `constexpr operator size_t` and values `0` through `N-1`, and passes those to a lambda you pass `unpack`.

Example use:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto print_later(Args&&... args) {
  auto lambda = [params = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)](
    auto&& stream
  )
  {
    unpack<sizeof...(Args)>( [&](auto...Is){
      using discard=int[];
      (void)discard{0,(void(
          stream << std::get<Is>( params )
        ),0)...
      };
    });
  };
  return lambda;
}
```

Notice the `Is` being passed to the inner lambda.  Basically this technique let us unpack a parameter pack and get its values in an expandible context without having to create a new explicit template function; instead, we create a variadic lambda, and use the types of the arguments (or constexpr operations on them) to get the unpack results.

The above is a function that takes a package of arguments, and returns a function that takes a stream and prints them all.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f30a72e757d3bc7e)

The `unpack` function can be made much more generic; at least, have it take a `integer_sequence`, and in the end even a variation could take a pack of types directly.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing something similar with an integer sequence, thus packaging and unpacking the arguments. Good hint the one of having a lambda that gets the indexes as an argument. I did it using a couple of function templates and nothing more.

Comment: wow, how does this black magic work:  using discard=int[];
            (void)discard {0,(( ....       everything is a mystery (void) , void(), array of discard... how the heck it works??)

Comment: @barney It is an array of ints cast to void, using comma operator to do a statement on each of the ints, and all the ints are 0.

Comment: @barney Why bother?  Because initializing an array is guaranteed in-order in C++, while many other contexts are not.

Comment: @Yakk amazing! never thought of a template pack expansion in a context of a void() cast, of array {}, within the , operator. That is true magic! Especially the ... pack expansion that fits smoothly with the , separated list of parameters inside this construct. Now the REAL question:: How did you invent it?? What should I smoke or ingest to be able to think in this way?))) its very cool indeed

Comment: @barney It is an old trick from stack overflow.  I don't know who invented it.

Comment: @Yakk I see. Thanks for sharing. It's very enlightening. wonder how many such tricks are still uncovered. C++ syntax "combinational base" is HUGE.

Comment: @barney I know how it was *found* -- they wanted to do exactly this, and needed a context in which a `...` expansion guaranteed ordered evaluation.  The unordered "foreach" and the recursive ordered "foreach" where both precursors.  I just don't know who first noticed that this (and similarly, `initializer_list<int>{ blah... }` solved the problem.

Comment: @Yakk hmm I see. Reverse thinking. So they needed some expression, that could be expandable to comma-separated sequence of parameters "..."  AND they knew that the resulting expanded sequence should be evaluated in strict order. So the array init list is a perfect match indeed. And then they just found the way to insert the "useful expression" to the sequence using the "operator comma" trick. The cast to void is to force usage of ",0" after the comma as a value (but it not necessary if operator, isn't overloaded, I believe OR maybe it should be here to silence the type mismatch?)